# Run Eve over HTTPS

Tags: python, https, flask, eve

How can I run my Eve app over HTTPS rather than HTTP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking into running your Eve application directly, with no real web server like nginx, apache, etc., then something like this would work:

```
import ssl
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
context.load_cert_chain('yourserver.crt', 'yourserver.key')

app.run(ssl_context=context, debug=True)
```

Or alternatively:

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
context = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
context.use_privatekey_file('yourserver.key')
context.use_certificate_file('yourserver.crt')

app.run(ssl_context=context, debug=True)
```

Now, both options would probably be good for testing with your own certificate. You can also take the `adhoc` shourtcut (will probably need `pyopenssl` installed):

```
app.run(ssl_context='adhoc', debug=True)
```

Remember you don't really want to run this in production. You need a proper server to do that, and all of them provide proper documentation on how to setup a secure connection for your application.